# Создание нескольких лейблов программно

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый вечер, нужно вывести количество элементов в очередях на разные лейблы. При нажатии кнопки печатается только количество элементов в первой очереди,найдите ошибку, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    M = int.Parse(textBox1.Text); //Количество очередей
    QArray = new Queue<int> [M];
    for (int i=0;i< M; i++)
    {
        QArray[i] = new Queue<int>();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int count = rnd.Next(1, 8); //Количество элементов в очереди
        for (int j=0;j< count; j++)
        {
            QArray[i].Enqueue(rnd.Next(1, 30));
        }
        Label label = new Label();
        label.Location = new Point(100+10*i, 100);
        label.Text = QArray[i].Count.ToString();
        this.Controls.Add(label);
    }
}
```

Comment: А что, собственно говоря, не так? Хотя нет, спрошу иначе, что именно не получается?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю,должно вывестись несколько лейблов с количеством элементов,например, в первой,второй и третей очередях(если M=3), у меня появляется только один лейбл с количеством элементов первой очереди,что делаю не так?

Comment: @DenisBubnov единственное не понимаю,почему количество элементов выводится одинаковое,сейчас все лейблы видно,но размер каждой очереди например равен 2,ведь на каждой итерации мы задаем новое количество.

Comment: Видимо так совпало...попробуйте задать больший разброс случайных чисел и запустите заново.

Comment: @DenisBubnov глупо,наверное, звучит, но при значения от 1 до 100 и введенной 5 в текстбокс на экран выводится пять шестерок..

Comment: @DenisBubnov переменная count все время одна и та же,в коде ошибки вроде нет,что делать?)

Comment: проблема в `Random`, загляните сюда: [Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ctssatww.aspx), дело в том, что он генерирует псевдослучайные числа...точно не помню, то там решалось это просто...по моему нужно было уникальное число передавать в конструктор, к примеру текущее время через `DateTime.Ticks`. Введите в поисковике, думаю найдете решение )

Comment: @DenisBubnov да,Вы правы,проблема в экземпляре класса Random была, нужно было строчку `Random rnd = new Random();` из цикла вынести,спасибо.

Comment: Отвечу на всякий случай заранее, если нажмете кнопку еще раз и будете рисовать в тех же местах Ваши лэйблы, то значения не поменяются, потому что новые лэйблы будут находиться под теми, которые были созданы ранее. Ну это так, на всякий случай Вам )

Comment: @DenisBubnov понял,спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Вашем коде нет ошибки, просто Ваши элементы перекрывают друг друга. Попробуйте внести следующее изменение:

```
label.Location = new Point(100 + 100 * i, 100);
```

Измените, к примеру `10 * i` на `100 * i` тогда уведите все элементы.

Comment: Действительно,спасибо огромное.